# Verify State in Script before Adding Line item (NetSuite)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to add a line to a Sales Oder when a specific item has been added, but before it does, I need it to verify the state first.

This is where my struggle comes in. I have the code to add the item correctly working, but my state check errors out.

```js
function validateField(type, name, linenumber) {
  var shipstate = nlapiGetFieldText()
  if (shipstate == 'PA') {
    function recalc(type) {
      if (type == 'item') {
        var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item');
        if (itemId == 1658) {
          //Insert item
          nlapiSelectNewLineItem('item');
          nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', 1516);
          nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1);
          nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount', '0.24');
          nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Any insight to where my issue is? 
I think my issue is where I'm storing the state value so it can check the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend adding your line with a `recalc` function instead of a `validateField` function. This is because if you try to add a new line while you are still editing an existing line it will cancel out of your current line. With a `recalc` function it will wait until you hit the 'Add' button on the existing line before checking the state and adding a new line.

You are on the right track with your state validation, the function you need is `nlapiGetFieldValue('shipstate');`. I believe the code below should solve your issue.

```
function recalc(type) {
    var shipstate = nlapiGetFieldValue('shipstate');
    if (shipstate === 'PA') {
        addNewLine(type);
    }
    return true;
}

function addNewLine(type) {
    if (type === 'item') {
        var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item');
        if (itemId === '1658') {
            //Insert item
            nlapiSelectNewLineItem('item');
            nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', '1516');
            nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', '1');
            nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount', '0.24');
            nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Jon, Thank you very much for your help. I copied your code and I got no errors! (Further than I got) But when I load a sales order for a customer in OH, It still adds the additional line item. It seems like it isn't storing the State for the verification check. Do you think it has something to do with the address being in a sublist? I verified that I can Calling on the correct field name {shipstate}. Thoughts?

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind logging the value of 'shipstate' when you load your sales order and tell me what you see? So at the beginning of the script after the `var shipstate = nlapiGetFieldValue('shipstate');` line add a new line like this `console.log('Ship State', shipstate);`. Then open up the browser console and look at the output.

Comment: Jon, I didn't even think of that. Log shows 'Ship State OH'. So it is verifying the state. Now i am just guessing it has to be part of the "true" statement isn't working correctly.

Comment: Jon, So doing more testing. I actually chose a customer in PA and the Script actually removes item 1658 and replaces it with item 1516 instead of adding a line. If i chose a customer out side of PA, When I add item 1658, it also adds in the item 1516. The preferred result. Weird.

Comment: Hmm, can you check that there are no other scripts running on Sales Order that might be affecting this? Go to Customization>Scripting>Scripted records, edit the Sales Order and uncheck the 'Deploy' checkbox on all the scripts except this one on the 'Client' tab and save. Also, verify that you have `validateLine` in the 'validateLine' field on the script record and nothing in the other fields. I tested this in my account and it appeared to work as you would like so I feel like it's something with the setup.

Comment: Jon, I still had the recalc listed on the script record. I removed that value from the field. I also went in and turned off all scripts and workflows.  I no longer have an issue when a customer is in another state. I still have an issue if the customer is in PA, it deletes the item 1658 add originally and replaces it with 1516 and I get a pop up asking me "Please choose an item to add" with a "OK" box. Again, thank you for all your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: And you have your function in the `validateLine` field on the script record? If you're trying to run it as a `validateField` function then it will do what you are experiencing. This is because the line you are on is not "committed" so it gets replaced by the new line. If you use `validateLine` then the original line gets "committed" before the new line gets added

Comment: Jon, Verified that the Validate Line Function has the "validateLine" function listed. No other boxes have any text. Really weird how it just started doing the delete and replace out of no where. I even went back in and copied and pasted your code again just to verify i didn't accidentally write over anything.

Comment: Ah, I see the error, sorry about that. Can you try using the recalc function instead of validate line, I mixed them up. Just stick `validateLine` into the recalc field and give it a go. In `validateLine` the line hasn't fully committed, in `recalc` it has. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Sounds like it's working! If you wouldn't mind clicking the check mark next to the answer to mark it as the accepted answer I would appreciate it.